# I have a microsoft word document and want to insert headings before every point in the original document through java. Any approaches?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a document say as follows:

### Heading Short Intro

1. List item i have a account on stack overflow
2. I use it to post questions
3. I use it to answer questions

I want to convert this into :

### Heading Short Intro - 1

1. List item i have a account on stack overflow

### Heading Short Intro - 2

2. I use it to post questions

### Heading Short Intro - 3

3. I use it to answer questions

Edit : I came to know that word itself has teh facility to make macros. So going through that. Challenge I am facing is how to iterate over number lists

Comment: Use Apache POI library to read and modify MS-Word documents.

Comment: yes but how do i go to the starting of every point?

Comment: Show your code... whatever you have tried yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it through Word Macro itself. Was easier. Bloew code should give you an idea :

```
Sub iterateNumberedList()
   Dim oList As Paragraph

   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst ' go to beginning of doc

 ' for each paragraph
   For Each oList In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

  ' is it a numbered list of level 1 ?
   If oList.Range.ListFormat.ListType = 4 And oList.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 1 Then

     ' move one line above list item
     Selection.MoveUp unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

     ' insert heading text
     Selection.Range.Text = "Heading " & vbCr

     ' format heading text with style 'Heading 1'
     Selection.Range.Style = "Heading 1"

     ' move down two paragraphs
     Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2
  End If
  Next
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy enough with docx4j or POI's XWPF.

In docx4j, the paragraphs (and tables etc - the block level elements) are contained in a list you can access as follows:

```
yourWordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent()
```